# Holonomic constraints and degrees of freedom

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Back in my undergrad I learned that in a dynamical system, if I add a holonomic constraint, I subtract one degree of freedom from the space of configurations. But one can think of situations in which one subtracts more than one: take a single particle, in polar cylindrical coordinates if I fix $r=0$ (*one* constraint), I have subtracted two degrees of freedom, and in polar spherical coordinates, I have subtracted  three degrees of freedom. For values greater than one everything is fine, the holonomic constraint subtracted one degree of freedom.

Is it that for $r=0$ the ones that I didn't fix became sort of "gauge" variables and they count as dynamical variables (because nothing is keeping them from taking whatever value they want), although they do nothing?

How do we know if this is the case for one generalized constraint?

Comment: I think your angles are undefined in both examples. If we define an angle between two line segments or curves etc. Its difficult to imagine what one might want without any reference of this kind.

Comment: One should count the number of degrees of freedom *before* solving the equations of motion. But in this case there are no possible Lagrangians for which the anglular coordinate is going to matter, so I am not sure how many degrees of freedom I am actually getting rid of with that single constraint.